# Find number of possible values satisfying $\cos \left(\pi\sqrt{x-4}\right)\cos \left(\pi\sqrt{x}\right)=1$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find number of possible values satisfying the equation:
>   $$\cos \left(\pi\sqrt{x-4}\right)\cos \left(\pi\sqrt{x}\right)=1$$

We are required to find the number of possible solutions for $x\in\Bbb R$.

I can't understand how to approach this.

Comment: You might want to learn the difference between "can't" and "don't" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since $\cos \theta \in [-1,1]$, and we're given the equation

$$\cos(\pi \sqrt{x - 4}) \cos(\pi \sqrt x) = 1$$

then either

$$\cos(\pi \sqrt{x - 4}) = \cos(\pi \sqrt x) = 1$$

or

$$\cos(\pi \sqrt{x - 4}) = \cos(\pi \sqrt x) = -1$$

Don't forget to invoke the periodicity of cosine as well.

Comment: Do not forget that $\cos(it)=\cosh(t)$ which makes the problem interesting.

Comment: How did you conclude that these two are the only possible cases?

Comment: It partly is from we know cosine cannot be outside $[-1,1]$. If two numbers $a,b$ satisfy

$$a \cdot b = 1$$

then it follows

$$a = \frac 1 b \;\;\; b = \frac 1 a$$

Obviously, if $b<1$ (left) or $a<1$ (right), then the right side is greater than $1$. Since both $a,b$ in this case are cosine functions, it follows we cannot have either be less than one. Thus, their product is $1$, as given, which would only be achieved if both were $1$ or $-1$.